# How do I use vim as 'git log' editor?

Tags: git, vim, pager, git-log

When I run `git log`, what exactly is the editor `git log` is using?

Also:

1. Is there anyway I can use `vim` as my default editor for `git log`?
2. If I want to search against the git log, what's the best way? Now I'm doing something like: `git log | grep bla`.

Comment: The output of `$ git log` is not something you edit so why exactly do you want to use an editor to view it?

Comment: @romainl mainly just try to search it. Since the guys pointed out, less has a subset of vim search functionality, I guess I can live with  less now.

Comment: less has `/`, `?`, `n` and `N`, it supports regex search. `$ man less` is a *very* interesting read.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `git log` command pipes it's output by default into a *pager*, not an editor. This pager is usually `less` or `more` on most systems. You can change the default pager to `vim` with the command:

```
git config --global core.pager 'vim -'
```

Now you can search using `vim` functionality with `/` as usual.

Comment: less obeys a subset of vim search functionality

Comment: @honk 'vim - ', what does '-' there do?

Comment: @Shengjie: It makes vim read from `STDIN`. Usually a good idea to add `-R` for read-only mode it that case as well.

Comment: @Shengjie: for many utilities, `-` as file name means `stdin` or `stdout` depending on context

Comment: git config --global core.pager 'vim -R -' , -R is important to quit quickly

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at **[viewlog](https://github.com/roubles/viewlog).**

It gives you a terminal gui interface to all commits. It will also open the file in the editor of your choice. You can search for relevant commits using the --grep flag.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
`git log | vim -R -`

Comment: Hey, what's point of hypen behind '-R'? (I found without '-' behind '-R', it works as well)

Comment: @d0zingcat this indicates "Readonly mode (like "view")

Answer (score 0):

I had write a bash script to switch from using vim as editor to diff-so-fancy.

```
VT() {
    gitlogflag=true
    if [ -e "$HOME/.myscriptvar" ] ; then
        gitlogflag=$(cat "$HOME/.myscriptvar")
    fi
    if [ "$gitlogflag" = true ]; then
        git config --global pager.show "vim -c '%sm/\\e.\\{-}m//g' -c 'setlocal buftype=nofile' -c 'set ft=diff' +3 -";
        gitlogflag=false
    else
        git config --global pager.show "diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=1,5 -RFX";
        gitlogflag=true
    fi
    echo "$gitlogflag" > $HOME/.myscriptvar
}
```

I recommend you to use [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy).

If you just want to use vim as your git log editor `git config --global pager.show "vim -c '%sm/\\e.\\{-}m//g' -c` will satisfy you.