# How do I use vim as 'git show' editor?

Tags: git, vim

all as described in [How do I use vim as 'git log' editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666009/how-do-i-use-vim-as-git-log-editor) doesn't work for git show .
I use often

```
git show HEAD

ctrl+z 

ps 

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7083 pts/8    00:00:06 bash
31758 pts/8    00:00:00 git
31759 pts/8    00:00:00 less
31762 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
```

Update I found the solution :

```
git config --global pager.color false
git config --global pager.show 'vim -R -'
```

Even better (2021-02-05)

```
git config --global core.pager 'vim -R -'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666055/778517

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
PAGER='vim -' git -c color.ui=false show
```

Comment: I guess he chose his update of his own post as the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Twitter post to solve that problem.

https://twitter.com/oliviergay/status/179692941063888896

> Using `git show` with `vim` and syntax highlighting: `vimgitshow() { git show "$1" | vim - "+set filetype=${1##*.}"; }`

Comment: also that is a bash function  like an alias , not solve the original problem just workaround it .

Comment: @Sérgio you put this into `~/.bashrc` so that it will be defined whenever you open a new terminal. then you can use `vimgitshow` instead of `git show`

Comment: What exactly does `+set filetype?${1##*.}";}` do?

Comment: (fix typo) where I put that  piece of code ?
thanks  lucidbrot

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
git config --global pager.show "vim -c '%sm/\\e.\\{-}m//g' -c 'set ft=diff' +1 -"
```

Crazy vim args found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015531/610634

Comment: I see `Error detected while processing command line:
E486: Pattern not found: \e.\{-}m`

Comment: You can suppress such warnings with the `/e` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use a better diff than just patch syntax highlighting. It allows you to use `git show` and see the diff for each file in `vimdiff`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192154/4653540).

Answer (score 0):

can simply use `git show bf9f84042 | vim -` in edit mod, or `git show bf9f84042 | vim -R -` in read only mod, without changing gitconfig

or

`git config --global diff.tool vimdiff` using vimdiff as diff.tool, and then `git difftool bf9f042 232wf2f` to diff