# Force git show to show diff using vimdiff

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff

How do I do this? After doing changes via `git config` I can diff my staged and committed changes with vimdiff but when I do `git show` I still see the diff in old plain style. How do I make this work for `git show` as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048270/how-do-i-use-vim-as-git-show-editor

Answer (score 4):

Try using git aliases. This is for `git show`

```
git config --global alias.s difftool\ HEAD^\ HEAD
```

And this is for `git show <revision>`

```
git config --global alias.s '!f() { rev=${1-HEAD}; git difftool $rev^ $rev; }; f'
```

To see how it works, get familiar with [this page](http://jondavidjohn.com/git-aliases-parameters/).

Comment: Actually this is a pretty good answer and is exactly what I was looking for. This works not only with HEAD but with any commit and it accepts filenames to show with '--'. Disabling the "Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]" prompt with 'git config difftool.prompt false' works even better. Thank you.

Comment: I think the second method is the one I was looking for. Can you explain what the ^ mark means?

Comment: Hey @ChanKim , sorry it took me so long. If it still matters, the "^" stands for "parent", so an expression "HEAD^" means the commit that's a parent of HEAD. Or , put it simply, previous commit. You can daisy-chain them like so "HEAD^^^" which means the same as "HEAD~3" which means "3 commits before HEAD". I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Following works for me:

```
git difftool SHA^..SHA -- <file>
```

Comment: Thanks! For others : for example, do `git difftool 0f27151b7^..0f27151b7 src/main.c`.

Answer (score 3):

The default `git show` with no parameter as well as `git show <object>` display changes to all files within a commit. Since vimdiff can only compare a single file at a time, you cannot use it with these options.

However `git show <object> -- <file>` shows the changes to a single file within a commit. You can display the changes in vimdiff by running `difftool` instead:

```
git difftool SHA~:SHA -- <file>
```

If you need more flexibility, you can always use `git show` to fetch specific versions of a file and pass them into vimdiff via [Process Substituion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
export FILE=path/to/file; vimdiff <(git show SHA1:$FILE) <(git show SHA2:$FILE)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `git show` you can show objects like commits ([see the man page for reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)). So you don't show a diff of two files, but changes in (maybe multiple) files. So there are not two files, which can be compared. But that is exactly what vimdiff does, it opens two files side-by-side and highlights differences.
When you use `git difftool` or something like that it will create files for both sides of the diff and use the tool (in your case vimdiff) to compare them. `git show` does not create those files, so its output can't be shown by vimdiff.

tl;dr: `git show` is a tool to display git objects, not to create diffs, so its output can't be shown as a diff using vimdiff.

What you might want to do is to use `git difftool`. It will open gvimdiff for every modified file.
You can use the usual options of `git diff` to compare different commits.